# Cannot move or resize anything. No applications have taskbars on startup

Tags: linux, kali-linux

On reboot, i cannot move or resize any windows and I have no option to close or minimize. Running xfwm4 fixes the issue entirely but it requires me to keep the terminal open and I have to do it every time I restart kali. Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to fix it permanently? I am running Kali Linux on bare metal.

I got the xfwm4 fix from another user on here with the same problem, this is his screenshot but it's the exact problem as mine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU8zD.png

Comment: Try running:    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
  and restart, test.

Comment: I generally advise against apt auto*

Answer (score 1):

You obviously don't have the window manager (xfwm) configured to launch.

Since it's debian derivative you should be able to `dpkg-reconfigure xfwm4` and select it as default.

If you're running `systemctl` you'll be able to set a rule there.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need to do to fix the problem is run this command at reboot the answer is simple.  [This Guide](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-isight-ubuntu-38894.html) says edit your crontab file with `sudo crontab -e` then add the line `@reboot xfwm4` to the first available line. The article has some alternatives if that doesn't work. Best of luck!